# Rails association finder_sql proc{} doesn't return all table columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations

I have this association in my `Page` model.

```
  has_many :networks, :finder_sql => proc {"SELECT * FROM network_pages WHERE page1_id = #{id} OR page2_id = #{id}"}
```

It retrieves the `Networks` via the page ids in the `NetworkPages` model. Their tables are as follows:

```
1.9.3p392 :010 > Network
 => Network(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, column1: string, column2: string, inversion: boolean) 
1.9.3p392 :011 > NetworkPage
 => NetworkPage(id: integer, network_id: integer, page1_id: integer, page2_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

However when calling the association above I only get id & timestamp columns of the record in return:

```
1.9.3p392 :014 > page.networks
 => [#<Network id: 1, created_at: "2013-04-07 09:07:05", updated_at: "2013-04-07 09:07:05">]
```

It returns the correct class but I can't call the other attributes:

```
1.9.3p392 :015 > page.networks.first.class
 => Network(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, column1: string, column2: string, inversion: boolean) 
1.9.3p392 :016 > page.networks.first.name
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: name
    from (irb):16
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

But there's no problems using `Network.find`

```
1.9.3p392 :017 > Network.find(1).name
  Network Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `networks`.* FROM `networks` WHERE `networks`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => "First Network Name"
```

I don't quite understand why this is happening, how do retrieve all of the `Network` models attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your finder_sql is selecting from the wrong table - network_pages instead of networks

Comment: Ah yes, I wonder why it returned a `network` class though. Is rails trying to fit the returned columns to the model?

Comment: `has_many :networks, :finder_sql => proc {"SELECT networks.* FROM networks INNER JOIN network_pages ON networks.id = network_pages.network_id WHERE page1_id = #{id} OR page2_id = #{id}"}`

Comment: It returned a network because you said has_many networks. It doesn't try and analyse the contents of the finder_sql to see which tables are being used